# mysql join - include null rows in joined table

Tags: mysql, join, null, where-clause

I have 4 mysql tables as follows:

attributes:

```
int          id
string       attribute
```

categories:

```
int          id
string       category
```

products:

```
int          id
int          category_id (fk categories.id)
string       name
...
```

attribute_category:

```
int          id
int          attribute_id (fk attributes.id)
int          category_id  (fk categories.id)
```

attribute_product

```
int          id
int          attribute_id (fk attributes.id)
int          product_id   (fk products.id)
string       value
```

A product has many attributes, however the attributes it **can have** are determined by which category the product is in.

I wish to perform crud operations on the product_attributes simultaneously with the products table.

**CREATE OPERATION**

I can get the attributes which a product requires:

```
SELECT 
    attributes.id, attributes.attribute 
FROM `attributes`
JOIN 
    `attribute_category`
ON 
    attributes.id = attribute_category.attribute_id
WHERE
    attribute_category.category_id = 1
```

**EDIT OPERATION**

When editing, I require the ability to join above table with the attribute_product table. This table should do three things:

1. Determine which attributes a product requires
2. List existing product attribute values
3. If a product attribute value does not exist, null should be placed in the value

my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    attributes.id, 
    attributes.attribute,
    attribute_product.value
FROM `attributes`
JOIN 
    `attribute_category`
ON 
    attributes.id = attribute_category.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN
    `attribute_product`
ON
    attributes.id = attribute_product.attribute_id
WHERE
    attribute_category.category_id = 1 AND
    attribute_product.product_id = 1
```

Now this query meets 1 and 2 of requirements, however I don't know what I need to do to meet part 3. e.g. If a product_attribute has not been entered, but should be available, I wish to return a row, with null as the value. In the first instance, I don't think I am using my left join correctly and in the second instance, by stating in my WHERE clause that the product_id must be 1, I am automatically excluding my null rows.

e.g required output.

```
attributes.id    attributes.attribute    attribute_product.value
1                Weight                  35.5
2                Height                  55.6
3                Colour                  null
7                Shape                   Round
9                Manufacturer            null
```

current output

```
attributes.id    attributes.attribute    attribute_product.value
1                Weight                  35.5
2                Height                  55.6
7                Shape                   Round
```

Comment: You can put the line AND attribute_product.product_id = 1 into the ON clause of the join instead of the WHERE clause

Comment: AAAH!!! Thanks Kickstart! Job done :)